# CORS Set Cookie Not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I have issue for not able being set cookie in cross domain scenario.

First of all, I would like to describe how was my scenario. Basically, I have 3 client platform those are web, ios, android. These 3 platforms would communicate with my backend endpoints.

For this question is only relates to Web and backend. Web and backend are in different domain.

My web (React JS) would host as http://webdomain1.com.
My auth endpoint (Spring Boot Application) would host as http://backenddomain1.com and listening port 8080

I'm using chrome to browse http://webdomain1.com and try to send authentication username and password via Ajax to http://backenddomain1.com and backend would issue token to web. The response would response 'Set-Cookie' and set the token into cookie. However, I don't see the cookie being set in http://webdomain1.com by inspecting from chrome developer tools.

Here is my ajax code:

```
axios({
            method:'post',
            url: 'http://backenddomain1.com/auth/rentilife/authenticate',
            data: this.loginModel,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
        }).then((response) => {
            document.cookie="test=value";
        }).catch(function (error) {
            //console.log(error);
        });
```

And my backend code as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Value("${allowed.origin.domains}")    
    private String[] allowedOriginDomains;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOriginDomains);
    }
}
```

And the response header as below:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://webdomain1.com
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 May 2017 11:34:17 GMT
Set-Cookie:XA=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhMWN8Y2h1YW5ob3I4NUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJnYWdlc2lzLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MzY0MjA1OCwiaWF0IjoxNDkzNjM4NDU4LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6aGAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.OGVpymzgOzoLhjdhJS6OMbYnCB1NhwfVxCP7E8dxSahKYZvE5lZBrMBN5xgylOZoOWLHRB0C28j2Ps6zO1s7KF_KuNI6lPn1hU2oCjGZkp4X2HGj1rPBhmB7jy5oXpBB0GZDu8HV5u-HeVh2HfDH1KaCw-pJdPH66y0e6ugJghR36StqfrphTu1ideSjsWgN7BTpVip_uVP8aDKjVLZsQjnntlVLqrrEt0wutn10xXDs5d_pULi3wn0s18IPQFWA9iiC0d8s5hNk-AdVKmMhD9wQrczxYoPO5WqKIf5SFFKHa7bYJPUNJ6mSw6zshS1Bnj1cn_joJ8wo9mKQr05Lhw;domain=webdomain1.com;path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-Application-Context:gateway:8080
```

Request Header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,la;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:backenddomain1.com:8080
Origin:http://webdomain1.com
Referer:http://webdomain1.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Seeking for guidance. Appreciate if somebody could help.

Comment: Session cookies (what i think you are trying to do) are only used on the same domain. What you are describing is more inline with the bearer token way of doing things. Have a look at https://oauth.net/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can't set cookies for another domain, as it would be a huge security problem to do so.
In your case, the first solution would be for `http://webdomain1.com` to send a request to your API and add the cookie from the response. This is needed if you really need the cookie on your website.
It may be possible to read the cookie information from the Headers, but I'm not sure about that.

Sample response:

```
{
    'auth':'Success',
    'cookieName':'yourCookie',
    'cookieValue':'eatoinshruldu'
}
```

Doing this will allow your different backends to implement their own solutions for authentification and security.

---

The other option is to perform the permissions and auth checks on your API domain only, and therefore set the cookie on this domain instead of your website.

Comment: Look like the work around only set cookie at the javascript site when getting the response. Exactly, I will implement the permission for the accessing authentication.